# Property of type MetaFile is buggy, how to get around it?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, properties, user-controls

I have a UserControl with a property called BackImage:

```
public Metafile BackImage { get; set; }
```

I then draw this image as a background on the UserControl in the Paint event with this code:

```
if (BackImage != null)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(BackImage, this.ClientRectangle);
```

I use a .wmf image as I need the vector format when resizing the UserControl.

When dragging the UserControl to a form at design time and setting this property via the properties window in Visual Studio the image is correctly shown when repainted.

The problem is that when running the program Visual Studio throws an "InvalidCastException" error in the designer file of the containing form. This is the line with the error:

```
this.imageControl1.BackImage = ((System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile)(resources.GetObject("imageControl1.BackImage")));
```

This is a well known bug in Visual Studio:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=425541

As the image must also be shown at design time it is no option to just load it at runtime.

**Question:**
Instead of the property being of type Metafile is it possible to use a kind of raw format, and then just convert or typecast it when using it in the code?

Comment: The link to the forum containing the "Bug" gives a 404.

Comment: This thread says that castign to `System.Drawing.Image` works. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?267897-WMF-(Metafile)-image-on-a-form-RESOLVED, maybe storing it as byte[] instead of image in the resources and loading it explicitly instead of casting is the safer solution.

Comment: I have seen the VB thread with System.Drawing.Image, the problem is that it gets converted to a bitmap then, and thereby I loose the vector format. How would I go about storing it as a byte[] in the resources? If I just add it to the resources in the regular way I assume it is stored as the file it is?

Comment: You would assume, but that's not what happens. As Hans also replied, the EMF is converted to a PNG upon serialization. Funny eh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is caused by the lack of support in GDI+ for encoding Emf/Wmf metafiles.  It can only read them.  The built-in image editor that you get when you select the metafile converts its to a PNG image to bypass the restriction.  You'll see it displayed in the designer, but it is not actually a metafile.  This PNG image is also what gets stored in the .resx file.  Kaboom when you then run your program, that PNG cannot be converted into a Metafile.

So a workaround is not make the property a Metafile, that just can't work.  I had quite a bit of trouble finding an alternative, the obvious choice of byte[] as the property type made the code serializer hang when trying to find a type converter.  Very strange, no idea why.  I settled on a `List<byte>` instead:

```
    private List<byte> BackImageBytes;

    [Editor(typeof(MyMetafileEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public List<byte> BackImage {
        get { return BackImageBytes; }
        set {
            BackImageBytes = value;
            if (value == null) base.BackgroundImage = null;
            else base.BackgroundImage = new Metafile(new System.IO.MemoryStream(value.ToArray()));
        }
    }
```

You'll need to override the BackgroundImage property so it doesn't get serialized:

```
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override Image BackgroundImage {
        get { return base.BackgroundImage; }
        set { base.BackgroundImage = value; }
    }
```

The Reset command in the context menu for the property is disabled, you need to add this go get it back:

```
    private void ResetBackImage() {
        BackImage = null;
    }
```

And finally you need a replacement for the default property editor, it needs to load a metafile and convert it to a list:

```
    class MyMetafileEditor : UITypeEditor {
        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) {
            using (var dlg = new OpenFileDialog()) {
                dlg.Filter = "Metafiles (*.wmf, *.emf)|*.wmf;*.emf";
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                    value = new List<byte>(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dlg.FileName));
                }
            }
            return value;                     
        }
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context) {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What an effort you put into this, very much appreciated! It's bet time here in Europe now, but I will look at it and get back ASAP!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help here! I got it working with a few comments as follows.

Comment: 1: I don't use the BackgroundImage property as I draw the image in the Paint event with e.Graphics.DrawImage(BackImage, this.ClientRectangle);. Therefore I changed the code a bit and assume that I don't need the overriding as you suggested.

Comment: 2: The reset command in the context menu gets enabled when adding a default value to the property: [DefaultValue(null)]. Isn't this a correct way to do this?